# Google chart showing blank using JSON

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I've been trying to get some Google Charts working from some data on a local db. I think I have got the JSON coming out properly now.

```
{
    "cols": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "label": "Inits",
            "pattern": "",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "id": "",
            "label": "SalesVal",
            "pattern": "",
            "type": "number"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "IS",
                    "f": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "1708.6000",
                    "f": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "NS",
                    "f": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "1098.8200",
                    "f": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "RC",
                    "f": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "458.8200",
                    "f": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm using this as the HTML.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've gone over it a few times and can't see where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs since `SalesVal` column is of `number` type  but the cells contain string values.

According to [Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam):

> `type [Required]` Data type of the data in the column. Supports the
>   following string values (examples include the v: property, described
>   later):
>
> - 'number' - JavaScript number value. Example values: `v:7 , v:3.14,    v:-55`

Having said that you could consider the following options:

**Option 1.** Modify `getData.php` endpoint to return a *valid* json data for `google.visualization.DataTable`:

```
"v": "1708.6000" //invalid (current) 
"v": 1708.6000   //valid
```

**Option 2**

Ensure data column of `number type` contain JavaScript number value as demonstrated below:

Example

```js
var jsonData = {
    "cols": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "label": "Inits",
            "pattern": "",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "id": "",
            "label": "SalesVal",
            "pattern": "",
            "type": "number"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "IS",
                    "f": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "1708.6000",
                    "f": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "NS",
                    "f": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "1098.8200",
                    "f": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "RC",
                    "f": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "458.8200",
                    "f": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};


google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(prepareJsonData(jsonData));
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, { width: 400, height: 240 });
}

function prepareJsonData(json) {
    json.rows.forEach(function(row) {
        row.c[1].v = parseFloat(row.c[1].v);  //ensure number cell value 
    });
    return json;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Got it returning a number instead of string and it came straight up. Thanks so much for the explanation.